# ¿Como filtrar un dataframe respecto a los valores de 2 columnas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Sigo aprendiendo Python y me toca manipular dataframes utilizando `pandas`.

Tengo una base de datos en donde los jugadores se ordenan por su `valor_potencial` y su `valor_actual` y se de la siguiente forma

```
id_jugador = [01,02,03,04,05,06,07]
valor_actual = [1000,1000,900,950,800,800,500]
valor_potencial = [1100,1200,900,950,1000,800,900]
```

Mi duda es en cómo filtrar el para que compare entre las columnas y solamente me muestre aquellos jugadores que su `valor_potencial` es superior a su `valor_actual`.

El output debe ser el siguiente:

```
id_jugador = [01,02,05,07]
valor_actual = [1000,1000,800,500]
valor_potencial = [1100,1200,1000,900]
```

En donde los jugadores 1, 2, 5 y 7 tienen un valor potencial mayor a su valor actual.

Mi duda es acerca de cómo filtrar tomando en cuenta el valor de una columna con respecto de la otra.

Les agradezco me puedan apoyar con su respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que crear el dataframe con los tres vectores y hacer una query donde valor potencial es mayor que valor actual, algo similar a esto:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 6),
...                    'B': range(10, 0, -2),
...                    'C C': range(10, 5, -1)})
>>> df
   A   B  C C
0  1  10   10
1  2   8    9
2  3   6    8
3  4   4    7
4  5   2    6
>>> df.query('A > B')
   A  B  C C
4  5  2    6
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Francisco. Tu respuesta me fue de mucha utilidad.